# Pass data from blade to vue component

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to learn vue and with that I want to integrate it with laravel too..
I simply want to send the user id from blade to vue component so I can perform a put request there.
Let's say I have this in blade:

```
<example></example>
```

How can I send Auth::user()->id into this component and use it.

I kept searching for this but couldn't find an answer that will make this clear.

Thanks!

Comment: Simply you can take this in your blade: `<span hashid="{{ Auth::user()->id }}"></span>` and in your vue component do like: `<script>
    export default {
        data: function () {
            return {
                hashid: ''
            }
        }
}
</script>` and console it anywhere, it'll give you auth id!

Comment: this might be usefull for you, its a free series about vue/laravel http://vuecasts.com

Comment: You can pass some variables by making them globally acessible in the window object, so in your app.blade.php have like a script tag defining a variable and then its easy to access it. though i would recomend looking at vue and front end as a separeted like an app that gets info through requests and JWT authentication

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To pass down data to your components you can use `props`. Find more info about props over [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Props). [This](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Prop-definitions-essential) is also a good source for defining those props.

You can do something like:

```
<example :userId="{{ Auth::user()->id }}"></example>
```

OR

```
<example v-bind:userId="{{ Auth::user()->id }}"></example>
```

And then in your `Example.vue` file you have to define your prop. Then you can access it by `this.userId`.

Like :

```
<script>
  export default {
    props: ['userId'],
    mounted () {
      // Do something useful with the data in the template
      console.dir(this.userId)
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are serving files through Laravel

Then here is the trick that you can apply.

In Your `app.blade.php`

```
@if(auth()->check())
<script>
    window.User = {!! auth()->user()  !!}
</script>
@endif
```

Now you can access `User` Object which available globally

Hope this helps.

Comment: Seems you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49664451/how-can-i-add-condition-on-vue-component-that-is-loaded-from-the-view-blade-lara

Comment: But vue.js throw the warning: vue.js:634 [Vue warn]: Error compiling template:

Templates should only be responsible for mapping the state to the UI. Avoid placing tags with side-effects in your templates, such as <script>, as they will not be parsed.

Comment: Can some one comment out if this approach is kinda safe?

Answer (score 0):

Calling component,

```
<example :user-id="{{ Auth::user()->id }}"></example>
```

In component,

```
<script>
    export default {
        props: ['userId'],
        mounted () {
            console.log(userId)
        }
    }
</script>
```

Note - When adding value to prop **userId** you need to use **user-id** instead of using camel case.

Answer (score 0):

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#blade-and-javascript-frameworks

Rendering JSON

Sometimes you may pass an array to your view with the intention of rendering it as JSON in order to initialize a JavaScript variable. For example:

```
<script>
    var app = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>;
</script>
```

However, instead of manually calling json_encode, you may use the @json Blade directive. The @json directive accepts the same arguments as PHP's json_encode function. By default, the @json directive calls the json_encode function with the JSON_HEX_TAG, JSON_HEX_APOS, JSON_HEX_AMP, and JSON_HEX_QUOT flags:

```
<script>
    var app = @json($array);

    var app = @json($array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just to add for those who still get error.
For me this `<askquestionmodal :product="{{ $item->title }}"></askquestionmodal>` still gives error in console and instead showing html page I saw white screen.

```
[Vue warn]: Error compiling template:
invalid expression: Unexpected identifier in
    Coupling to connect 2 rods М14 CF-10
  Raw expression: :product="Coupling to connect 2 rods М14 CF-10"
```

Though in error I can see that $item->title is replaced with its value.
So then I tried to do like that `<askquestionmodal :product="'{{ $item->title }}'"></askquestionmodal>`

And I have fully working code.

/components/askquestionmodal.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>{{ product }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "AskQuestionModal",
        props: ['product'],
        mounted() {
           console.log('AskQuestionModal component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
```