# How to pass an object from Laravel to Vue without using props

Tags: laravel, vue.js, global-variables, laravel-blade

I'm setting up some Vue Components in my Laravel 5.8 application, that require user information available through `Auth::user()`, most importantly, the `api_token` that I must use in my axios requests. I want to pass the `Auth::user()` object from Laravel to Vue in a secure and private method.

I initially passed the object as props, but I don't want private information on the object to be easily exposed using browser extensions such as Vue DevTools. Now, I've been searching for a way to define global variables inside the Blade Template and access them in Vue:

[Pass data from blade to vue component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49298845/pass-data-from-blade-to-vue-component)

https://forum.vuejs.org/t/accessing-global-variables-from-single-file-vue-component/638

https://zaengle.com/blog/layers-of-a-laravel-vue-application

Based on those links above, it seems like what I need to do is set the variables to the window object, but I'm unsure on what I'm doing something wrong to achieve this. When I define the variable in the Blade Template, I can see the variable is assigning properly by doing `console.log()` but the problem comes when I try to use it in Vue.

**app.blade.php**

```
@if(Auth::user())
    <script>
        window.User = {!! json_encode(Auth::user()) !!}
        console.log(window.User)
    </script>
@endif
```

**component.vue**

```
<script>
export default {
    data: function() {
        return {
            user: window.User
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I've tried setting the data as `window.User`, `this.User`, and simply just `User` but it always comes up as `undefined`. What am I missing? Or is there any other/better way to do this?

Comment: I tried `console.log(window.User)` and the console print the user data normally.

Comment: If you pass something to JS, it'll be accessible from the browser. Though, not "secure" or "private"

Comment: Anyway, Vue DevTools are available when you run `npm run dev`, on production you have to go with `npm run build` or something similar, maybe `npm run prod`

Comment: @Phil Yes, as I said, the console.log() does display the data, but when I try to assign it to a variable in Vue, like `user: window.User` it says it's undefined.

Comment: @Tarasovych So my variables and components won't show up once I build in production? My goal is simply to not have the data user readable by third party tools, so if the props do not appear in DevTools, I might stick to that solution

Comment: *"So my variables and components won't show up"* - yes, if we're talking about Vue DevTools

Answer (score 0):

Try the following Vue Component:

```
<template></template>

<script>
    export default {
        data: function() {
            return {
                user: window.User
            }
        },
        created(){
            console.log(this.user)

        },
    }
</script>
```

I could see the user data from the `console.log` in Vue component.