# Pass data from blade to vue and keep parent-child in sync?

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I know that in Vue parents should update the children through [props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-to-Child-Components-with-Props) and children should update their parents through [events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Listening-to-Child-Components-Events).

Assume this is my parent component `.vue` file:

```
<template>
<div>
    <my-child-component :category="category"></my-child-component>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: {
     return {
       category: 'Test'
     }
  }
}
</script>
```

When I update the `category` data in this component, it will also update the category props in `my-child-component`.

Now, when I want to use Vue in Laravel, I usually use an inline template and pass the value from the blade directly to my components (as for example also suggested at https://stackoverflow.com/a/49299066/2311074).

So the above example my `my-parent-component.blade.php` could look like this:

```
@push('scripts')
   <script src="/app.js"></script>
@endpush

<my-parent-component inline-template>
    <my-child-component :category="{{ $category }}"></my-child-component>
</my-parent-component>
```

But now `my-parent-component` is not aware about the data of `category`. Basically only the child knows the `category` and there is no communication between parent and child about it.

How can I pass the data from blade without breaking the parent and child communication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had to pass the `category` to the inline-template component through `props` like this:

```
@push('scripts')
   <script src="/app.js"></script>
@endpush

<my-parent-component :initcategory="{$category}}" inline-template>
    <my-child-component v-model="category"></my-child-component>
</my-parent-component>
```

In `my-parent-component` I had to set the props and initialize is using the create method:

```
export default {
  props: {
    initcategory: '',
  },
  data() {
    return {
      category: '',
    };
  },
  created(){
    this.category = this.initcategory;
  }
}
```

Now my `my-parent-component` is fully aware of the category and it can communicate to the child using `props` and `$emit` as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Your reference to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49298845/pass-data-from-blade-to-vue-component/49299066#49299066) is different altogether from what you are looking for!

He's binding the `:userId` prop of the `example` component but not the parent component or in simple words: Any template using the `example vue` can either pass a `string` prop or bind `:userId` prop to a string variable. Following is similar:

`<example :userId="{{ Auth::user()->id }}"></example>`

OR

`<example :userId="'some test string'"></example>`

So you should rather assign `{{ $category }}` to a data variable but rather binds to a child component `prop` which will have no effect on the parent.

In the following snippet you're only binding the string but rather a data key:

`<my-child-component :category="{{ $category }}"></my-child-component>`

**Update**

See the following example which will change the `h1` title after **3 seconds**

```
 // HelloWorld.vue
<template>
 <app-name :name="appName" @appNameChanged="appName = $event"></app-name>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['name'],
        data() {
            return {
                appName: null
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            // NOTE: since Strings are immutable and thus will assign the value while objects and arrays are copied by reference
            // the following is just for the purpose of understanding how binding works
            this.appName = this.name;
        }
    }
</script>
```

The template which renders the app title or you can say the **child component**

```
// AppName.vue
<template>
   <h1>{{ name }}</h1>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['name'],
        mounted() {
          setTimeout(() => {
             this.$emit('appNameChanged', 'Change App')
          }, 3000);
        }
    }
</script>
```

And here's how it is being used in the `welcome.blade.php`

```
<div id="app">
  <hello-world :name="'Laravel App'"></hello-world>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry I dont get your answer. I would like to pass a variable as a prop to the child that I can modify any time from the parent. In addition, the first content of the variable will be passed by the blade.

Comment: @Adam See the updated example and let me know if it works