# how to access data ($count) from laravel controller to vue component

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-controller

I want to access a variable $count from my controller and access it to a vue component (frontend). currently have this code on my controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $count = User::where('created_at', Carbon::today())->count();
    return view('user.index', compact('count'));
}
```

i am quite new to laravel and vuejs so please help me out. thank you!

Comment: define component in user/index.blade.php file. $count is available in blade file so passed as prop in component definition.

Comment: @JinalSomaiya hi! thank you for taking the time to answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Send count as a prop from blade to component

```html
<your-component-name :count="{{ $count }}"></your-component-name>
```

And from your component, receive that prop

```html
<template>
    <div>
        Count is {{ count }}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: {
        count: {
            type: Number
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: hi! thank you for taking the time to answer :)

Comment: Not at all, I hope it worked

Answer (score 0):

> To pass down data to your components you can use props. Find more info
> about props over here. This is also a good source for defining those
> props.
>
> You can do something like:
>
> ```
> <example :userId="{{ Auth::user()->id }}"></example>
> ```
>
> OR
>
> ```
> <example v-bind:userId="{{ Auth::user()->id }}"></example>
> ```
>
> And then in your `Example.vue` file you have to define your prop. Then
> you can access it by this.userId.
>
> Like :
>
> ```
> <script>
>   export default {
>     props: ['userId'],
>     mounted () {
>       // Do something useful with the data in the template
>       console.dir(this.userId)
>     }
>   }
> </script>
> ```

the above question was answered in below question
[Pass data from blade to vue component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49298845/pass-data-from-blade-to-vue-component)

Comment: hi! thank you for taking the time to answer :)